# Jquery FadeOut and FadeIn - setting display style

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm dealing with jquery fade function and I figured that fadeOut() adds the "display:none" style, and fadeIn() adds some display property.. sometimes it's "display:table" and sometimes it's "display:list-item".

My questions are..

How does jquery decide what it will transform the display style into when you fade in? It seems a bit random.

Isn't there a way to simply remove the "display:none" style and leave it as it was before fading out?

Comment: it decieds base on the HTML tag, for example <div> will be displayed as block, and <button> will be displayed as inline-block.

Answer (score 0):

You can fade an element in and out without using `"display:none"` using jquery's `.animate()` function.

If you want the element to be initially hidden, use

```
.element {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Then when you want to fade it in, use

```
$('.element').animate({opacity: 1});
```

And when you want to fade out, use

```
$('.element').animate({opacity: 0});
```

Check out the docs on `.animate()` [here](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).

And here's a simple jsfiddle demonstrating what I described above: http://jsfiddle.net/ea23wwqm/

Answer (score 0):

The best way to answer this is to look at the jQuery source code. I dug around and found `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` call `animate`. At some point, there are some calls to display/hide the item and you can find how that is done here:

[src/css/showHide.js#L19-L23](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/css/showHide.js#L19-L23):

```
    if ( show ) {
        if ( display === "none" ) {
            // Restore a pre-hide() value if we have one
            values[ index ] = dataPriv.get( elem, "display" ) || "";
        }
```

Then the actual call to show it:

[src/css/showHide.js#L36-L40](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/css/showHide.js#L36-L40):

```
for ( index = 0; index < length; index++ ) {
    if ( values[ index ] != null ) {
        elements[ index ].style.display = values[ index ];
    }
}
```

Based on that, we know the answer is that jQuery sets the `element.style.display` to `""` if it doesn't already have a pre-existing value for it (if it was hidden before, it saves the pre-hide display value). So it falls back to the browser!